# Can the Hermitian conjugate of a column vector still be column vector?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

From what I understand, contravariant vectors are represented by column vectors, and covariant vectors are row vectors. So for a QED current, say $j ^ { \mu } = \overline { \psi } \gamma ^ { \mu } \phi$ is a contravariant 4-vector = column 4-vector.

Now there's a (quite common I think) transformation that swap the order of the spinors appear in the current, in order to quickly calculate another QED current using the previously known one. It is just:

$$\begin{align}[j^\mu]^\dagger &=[\overline{\psi} \gamma^\mu \phi]^\dagger \\ &= [\psi^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^\mu \phi]^\dagger \\ &= \phi^\dagger \gamma^{\mu\dagger} \gamma^{0 \dagger} \psi \\ &= \phi^\dagger \gamma^{\mu\dagger} \gamma^0 \psi \\ &= \phi^\dagger \gamma^0 \gamma^\mu \psi \\ &=\overline{\phi} \gamma^\mu \psi\end{align}$$

which I noticed is also a column vector. So I did a transpose on a column 4-vector, and yet it stays at the same column form?

What did I do wrong, or misunderstood? Thank you!

Comment: No, by definition. Under transposition a column vector goes to a row vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the $\phi$ should be $\psi$, but that's just notation. Secondly, the $\mu$ indices are not the spinor indices- they simply label the component of the four current as $j^{\mu}=(\rho,\mathbf{J})$. In QFT, we have to be careful with objects that have spinor indices. The $\gamma$ matrices have both Lorentz indices $\mu$, which refer to which of the them they are. They also have spinor indices that have to be take into account when performing calculations with $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$. From the computation of $j^{\mu}$, you are expecting a number, i.e. the component of the current.

Comment: I see, so the $j^\mu$ is just a scalar. Can I ask what is the common notation? Is it usually that $j$ would be the 4-vector current, and $j^\mu$ as a component of that vector?

Comment: You can just look at the matrix structure of $j^{\mu}$- 1x2 row multiplied by 2x2 matrix multiplied by 2x1 column gives 1x1, which is a scalar. There is nothing wrong with the notation, although I'd be careful calling $j^{\mu}$ a scalar. It is a four vector. However, for each $\gamma^{\mu}$, you compute a component of the 4-current.